# failed to mount overlay: no such device when start docker in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: docker

when I am using this command to start dockerd in Raspberry Pi 4, it shows me this error:

```
raspberrypi% sudo dockerd
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.229201974+08:00] Starting up                                  
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.232284275+08:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.232347219+08:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.232413200+08:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.232450033+08:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.234828378+08:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.234934914+08:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.234993914+08:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.235048172+08:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
ERRO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.243143273+08:00] failed to mount overlay: no such device       storage-driver=overlay2
ERRO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.252902246+08:00] AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems       storage-driver=aufs
ERRO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.259121107+08:00] failed to mount overlay: no such device       storage-driver=overlay
WARN[2020-07-26T18:41:15.275937636+08:00] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit 
WARN[2020-07-26T18:41:15.275994209+08:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs period 
WARN[2020-07-26T18:41:15.276022875+08:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas 
WARN[2020-07-26T18:41:15.276049431+08:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period 
WARN[2020-07-26T18:41:15.276075449+08:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime 
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.276550759+08:00] Loading containers: start.                   
WARN[2020-07-26T18:41:15.287555903+08:00] Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.97-v7l+/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: WARNING: Module bridge not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.97-v7l+
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.97-v7l+/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: WARNING: Module br_netfilter not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.97-v7l+
, error: exit status 1 
WARN[2020-07-26T18:41:15.428797118+08:00] Running iptables --wait -t nat -L -n failed with message: `iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables):  CHAIN_ADD failed (No such file or directory): chain PREROUTING`, error: exit status 4 
INFO[2020-07-26T18:41:15.981245605+08:00] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables):  CHAIN_ADD failed (No such file or directory): chain PREROUTING
 (exit status 4)
```

what should I do to fix this problem? This is my docker install commamd:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh --mirror Aliyun
sudo apt install docker
sudo usermod -aG docker pi
```

this is my Raspberry Pi kernel version:

```
raspberrypi% uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.97-v7l+ #1294 SMP Thu Jan 30 13:21:14 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: If you install docker with apt there is a good chance that docker will be started when the raspi boots. Even apt should start docker after installation. Try e.g. `docker ps` to check if docker works.

Comment: not running.`raspberrypi% sudo docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` @PeterPaulKiefer

Comment: Are you sure that your user is `Pi`with a capital P?  usernames are case sensitive. But this should not deny the starting of dockerd, it just allows you to  use docker as a normal user. [I used: `sudo usermod -aG docker pi` on my raspis]. After logout and login again the docker command can be run from the pi user without sudo. Try `ps -ef  | grep dockerd` to be sure that the dockerd is not running.

Comment: I changed the user to pi and relogin , it still not work.@PeterPaulKiefer my kernel support    docker obviously.

Comment: It is more important to find out, whether docker is running so please what is the output of `ps -ef  | grep dockerd`? If it is not running, you have to start it manually. Then you have to use the systemctl command or the initd-commands. That depends on your linux version. if systemd is installed the journalctl command tells you why a module could not be started. On a initd system you have the syslog files in /var/log/. Perhaps they contain some infos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it needs to open cgroup in kernel level of Raspberry pi, I add cgroup config to the kernel by modify cmdline.txt:

```
cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1 swapaccount=1
```

and this is my full config:

```
raspberrypi% cat /boot/cmdline.txt 
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=ea7d04d6-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1 swapaccount=1 rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

this is the [page](https://medium.com/@tukai.anirban/docker-on-raspberry-pi-getting-started-c7b403205ecf) I am conference.

Comment: So this solves your problem?

Comment: yes,solve my problem.@Dirk

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: This worked on ubuntu focal 20..04.3, Linux 5.4.0-1045-raspi
  and allowed me to use overlay2 instead of devicemapper!    My service file in `usr/lib/systemd/system` needed this change `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --storage-driver=overlay2`.  .